# Access 2013 slow

Tags: ms-access, office-2013

I have several databases that I created and/or manage in Access.  Since we've upgraded to Office 2013 database performance has decreased significantly and I have been searching for answers, but not finding much help.

For example, processes that used to take minutes (macros, some using VBA and some not) now take much longer - one process that appends data to SQL tables to update a website now takes hours when it used to take minutes.  I have moved a lot of my databases off our network to my hard drive which helps some but they still run slower than they used to. I have done compact and repair and run code to change the Subdatasheet name property from auto to none on all of the tables.  But even simple things like filtering by form now takes minutes instead of seconds.

I know our company has network issues, a lot of other employees tell me they have problems with our network, but I still experience performance issues even when the database is on my hard drive and this has gotten much, much worse since we upgraded to office 2013.  There were/are also problems with Excel and other office programs - I turned off a lot of the visual effects in windows which helped a bit with excel, but not so much with Access.

Answer (score 0):

My company had a very similar experience with Office 2013.  UI elements are sluggish, especially in Excel.  Our power users were being slowed down by the non-responsive UI.  We tried many many different things (i.e. turning down visual effects in windows, turning off hardware acceleration, etc.)

In the end, we went back to Office 2010.

With that said, it sounds like the problems that you are experiencing in Access should have nothing to do with the UI (i.e. queries running etc.)

Do you have the capability to test from office 2010 again?  (i.e. a VM or other computer that has not yet been upgraded?)  Perhaps some processes can be run from the old version of office until you determine a root cause (if you can).

Comment: Unfortunately, no we do not have the ability to go back to 2010.  They push out the upgrades automatically to all machines.  We actually had the requirement for office 2010 for a large contract and our IT department said it was not possible...